# Recursive definition for the length of a string?

Tags: recursion, discrete-mathematics, induction

I found a couple of answers online but I don't quite understand why the answer is right:

1. The length of a string is:
   If a string has no characters, then its length is 0.
   Otherwise, the length of the string is 1 + length of the tail
2. 

[image]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are concatenations of characters. Hence, any non-empty string $w$ has a first character $x$ and can be written as $w = x w'$, where $w'$ is the tail string. It follows from the definition of a string's length that $|w| = |x w'| = |x| + |w'| = 1 + |w'|$.